# Run-time error '3704' with multipage userform

Tags: vba, excel, ado, userform

I am trying to build a simple front end to a database by building a userform via VBA in Excel. The form is multipage. When I was working on the first page, and would open the userform with `UserForm1.Show vbModeless`, I had no issues. The second page was present, just contained nothing. For background, the first page is a place to input information to insert into the database, the second is going to be a page to edit those fields and update a record. Now that I started building the second page, whe I try to launch the userform using `UserForm1.Show vbModeless`, I receive the following error. All that each page contains is a bunch of labels each with a corresponding text box or combo box.

`Run-time error '3704'`

`Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.`

How do I open this in order to show it?

The code being called to open the userform is:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Show_Form()
UserForm1.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

The initialize code is:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String, NextAM As String

With conn
    .Provider = "SQLOLEDB"
    .ConnectionString = "DATA SOURCE = server;Initial Catalog=database;INTEGRATED SECURITY=sspi;"
    .Open
End With

strSQL = "SELECT MAX(RIGHT(AM_Ref,6)) + 1 FROM AM"

rst.Open strSQL, conn

With ThisWorkbook
    If Len(rst(0)) = 3 Then
        .Sheets("Lists").Range("Next_AM") = "AM_000" & rst(0)
    ElseIf Len(rst(0)) = 4 Then
        .Sheets("Lists").Range("Next_AM") = "AM_00" & rst(0)
    ElseIf Len(rst(0)) = 5 Then
        .Sheets("Lists").Range("Next_AM") = "AM_0" & rst(0)
    End If

    Me.AM_Ref.Text = .Sheets("Lists").Range("Next_AM").Value2
End With

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing


With Me
    .StartUpPosition = 0
    .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
    .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
End With

End Sub
```

Please note, the initialize sub is the same as it previously was. If I have been unclear at all (likely) please let me know and I can clarify.

Cheers!

Comment: your issue is bc you close the rst/conn

Comment: Way to make me feel stupid @DougCoats! But many thanks for the quick response. Why does that cause the issue?

Comment: well if the connection is close & the record set is closed, then you cannot do anything with the records

Comment: But I am not trying to do anything with either the recordset or connection after they are closed. The only thing that happens after they are closed is setting up the position of the userform. It certainly fixed the issue, but is somewhat of a head scratcher for me.

Comment: i think the issue youre having isnt fully understood w/o the rest of the code...

Comment: There is no more code. I attach `Sub Show_Form()` to a button click on a worksheet, and then have my initialization sub. No other code is applicable here.

Comment: well it has to be. Reason I say is that you state page2 of multi page is supposed to updated records yet youre telling me there is no more relevant code. So, either there is no more code, and youre issue really is just "you closed the record set so now you cant interact with it" or there is more code....

Comment: check my last commnet, sorry forgot to tag you

Comment: I stripped this down so the only code left in the workbook is the `Show Form()` sub and the initialize routine. If I move the lines that close and discharge the recordset and connection to the end, it works, if I move them above the userform positioning it doesn't. I am still confused as to why that is since I am not interacting with either the recordset or connection after closing them, but it works, so I'm not sure how much it matters. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score -1):

Couple quick fixes and you should be off and running:

1) Change `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()` to `Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()`

2) In the master sub when you want to launch `UserForm` use the following:

```
Public Sub MasterSub()
   Dim UserForm as UserForm1
   .... code ..... 
   'Now ready to use the UserForm:
   Set UserForm = New UserForm1
   'UserForm will already be initialized and ready to be shown if you did not include that in your initialize sub
   UserForm.Show
End Sub
```

Hope this helps,
TheSilkCode